# where does the people picker control get its data from?

Tags: 2013, user-profile, people-picker

I have a sharepoint hosted add-in which includes some people picker controls. In these people picker there are all of the users available which are also available through the Active directory but if I check the users on my site collection I can only see a few of them (not all of the AD user where created here).

So where does the people picker control get its data from? Directly from the AD or from a "boss"-DB on the sharepoint server?

Answer (score 6):

The People Picker has three sources:

1. Active Directory (or the configured identity provider)
2. The User Information List. The UIL is stored in the SharePoint Content Database `UserInfo` table. These are users you've already added to the Site Collection.
3. The User Profile Service Application for Audiences only, as well as augmenting information to People pulled from one of the two sources above.

Comment: but if I am looking for users which are not in the UIL is the people picker always calling the AD? or is he storing the already queried user in the UIL?

Comment: See 1). The provided sources are in the answer.

Comment: yeah i red them. `These are users you've already added to the Site Collection.` but there are also users which I never added to the site collection which I can search using people picker...

Comment: Again, see 1). Active Directory.