# Fill SharePoint People Picker from SharePoint List Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, development, web-part, custom-web-parts

I have a SharePoint List who has the column of type `Person or Group`.

In my webpart solution I am trying to use Caml Query to get the Data of the List based on `Department` column. Each Department is assigned with `Multiple` Number of `Persons`.

I want to fill a Dropdown to Select Person from Dropdown and the Dropdown must be filled with the data returned based on Department

I've gone through [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210992/where-does-the-people-picker-control-get-its-data-from) but couldn't find any solution of using my own list in SharePoint People Picker Control

Following is the Image of my List:

[image]

Please Help, How can I Fill People Picker Control using this List in C# Solution

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the code snippet below ?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code snippet for your reference:

.ascx:

```
<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker runat="server" ID="PeoplePickerControlName" Required="true" ValidationEnabled="true" InitialHelpText="text" VisibleSuggestions="3" Rows="1" AllowMultipleEntities="true" CssClass="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" />
```

ascx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FillUser.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SPSite site=new SPSite("http://sp/sites/jerry"))
            {
                SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
                SPList list = web.Lists["JerryList4"];
                SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(6);
                SPFieldUserValueCollection reviewers = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item["Reviewers"];
                List<PickerEntity> reviewersEntity = new List<PickerEntity>();
                foreach (SPFieldUserValue spuserval in reviewers)
                {

                    SPUser userToassign = spuserval.User;
                    PickerEntity entity = new PickerEntity();
                    PeopleEditor pe = new PeopleEditor();
                    entity.EntityData["AccountName"] = spuserval.User.LoginName;
                    entity.EntityData["SPUserID"] = spuserval.User.ID;
                    entity.EntityData["Email"] = spuserval.User.Email;
                    entity.Key = spuserval.User.LoginName;
                    entity.Description = spuserval.User.LoginName;
                    entity.DisplayText = spuserval.User.Name;
                    entity = pe.ValidateEntity(entity);
                    entity.IsResolved = true;
                    reviewersEntity.Add(entity);
                }
                PeoplePickerControlName.AddEntities(reviewersEntity);
                }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]